# Trying to read particular Xml value using C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I'm new with C#. please help me.

**data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DataSet1 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd">
  <Language>
    <Id>001</Id>
    <English>"Welcome to India"</English>
    <German>"Willkommen in Indien"</German>
  </Language>
</DataSet1>
```

How to read value of `Id` using C# Xml? I'm new with C#. please help me.

**My effort:**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\data.xml");

while(reader.Read())
{
    reader.MoveToContent();
    if (reader.IsStartElement("DataSet1"))
    {
        reader.ReadToDescendant("Language");

        string str2 = reader.Name.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(str2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd strongly advise you to use LINQ to XML, which is a much simpler API than `XmlDocument`, and has excellent namespace support. Here's an example to get the `Id` value with LINQ to XML:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;          

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd";

        string id = doc.Root           // From the root...
            .Element(ns + "Language")  // select the Language direct child...
            .Element(ns + "Id")        // and the Id child of that...
            .Value;                    // and then take the text value
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

Obviously if your XML doesn't just have a single `Language` element you'll need to pick the right one, etc. You should read the [LINQ to XML documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/programming-guide-linq-to-xml) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use XmlDocument, if you Need further help leave a comment :)

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument("YourXmlString");

XmlNodeList xNodes = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("Id");

string Wished = xNodes[0].InnerText;
```

Little bit of explanation:

I recommend XmlDocument a lot because I really like to work with it myself, and besides that it has some pretty neat features to explore. Besides that, it is easy to get or to iterate through nodes

Comment: I find it *much* harder to use `XmlDocument` than LINQ to XML, particularly when namespaces are involved - or when building documents. (It's harder to query as well - LINQ to XML integrates very nicely with LINQ, as you'd expect from the name.)